# Function to trigger animation with mouse wheel events

Tags: javascript, beginner, event-handling

I am new in the JavaScript world and I just want to know if I can optimize my function by making it shorter. It already works but I plan to add five timelines to trigger with my slidenum variable. Here is the code :

```
var slidenum = 0;
var skrollViewport = document.getElementById('wrapper');
skrollViewport.addEventListener('wheel', skrollSlide);

function skrollSlide(event) {
    var delta;
    if (event.wheelDelta) {
        delta = event.wheelDelta;
    } else {
        delta = -1* event.deltaY;
    }
    if (delta <0) {
        slidenum++;
    } else if (delta >0) {
        slidenum = slidenum>0 ? --slidenum : 0;
    }
    if (slidenum > 0) {
        slide1.play()
    } else if (slidenum < 1) {
        slide1.reverse()
    }
    if (slidenum > 1) {
        slide2.play()
    } else if (slidenum < 2) {
        slide2.reverse()
    }
    console.log(slidenum);
}
```

Comment: I'm using greensock lib.

Comment: what is a *timeline* in this context? Do you consider `slide1` and `slide2` as timelines?  Those are tweens (i.e. result of calling `TweenLite.to()`), right?

Comment: Yes, slide1 and slide2 are two different timelines.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var delta;
if (event.wheelDelta) {
    delta = event.wheelDelta;
} else {
    delta = -1* event.deltaY;
}
```

could be simplified to:

```
var delta = event.wheelDelta ? event.wheelDelta : -event.deltaY;
```

or even more succinctly:

```
var delta = event.wheelDelta || - event.deltaY;
```

For the if/else:

```
if (slidenum > 0) {
    slide1.play()
} else if (slidenum < 1) {
    slide1.reverse()
}
```

I personally find your end points take me a while to understand because of the way they overlap. I would find it easier like this:

```
if (slidenum >= 1) {
    slide1.play()
} else if (slidenum < 1) {
    slide1.reverse()
}
```

Or without the else which is redundant in this case.

```
if (slidenum > 0) {
    slide1.play()
} else {
    slide1.reverse()
}
```